# Mysql Query Join two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two simple tables about one about dog breeds and one with dog names.

```
Breeds:

DogId  DogBreed                         

   1    boxer                            
   2     Lab                              
   3    Sheppard

Names:

DogId   DogName
   1      Max
   1      duke
   2      Jack
   2      Socks
   3      Lassie
```

The results I am looking for is

```
boxer - duke, max
Lab- jack, socks
Sheppard- Lassie
```

I have tried Inner joins, but I really can't figure this out, it seems so easy. Any help would be very welcome

Comment: join on DogID and use `GROUP_CONCAT(dogName)` and `group by DogID, DogBreed`  Show the SQL you've tried we'll help.  I'd probably name the dogID column BreedID. and dogID in names BreedID and have a separate ID for DogID for each name.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a single column returned with the format `dogbreed - dogname1, dogname2, dognameN` ? Or are these two separate columns returned: `dogbreed   |    dogname1, dogname2, dogname3`

Comment: Do you need the output like this in SQL, or in the app you are building? If the latter, you could just do a simple JOIN and do a loop in your program's language to display the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

Inner queries will slow down the performance (because of higher execution time) if you have large number of records.

Optimised SQL Query:

```
SELECT b.DogBreed,GROUP_CONCAT(n.DogName) FROM Breeds b 
LEFT JOIN `Names` n ON n.DogId=b.DogId
GROUP BY n.DogId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Try,

```
Select 
    b.dogbreed,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT n.dogname
        ORDER BY n.dogname ASC SEPARATOR ', '
    ) dognames
from breeds b
join names n on n.dogid = b.dogid
group by b.dogbreed
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
 SELECT b.dogbreed , (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DogName) 
FROM NAMES WHERE DogId = b.DogId ) AS DogNames FROM Breeds b
```